# XML Descendants v/s Child Node

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have this XML

```
<globalSettings>
<a>V1</a>
<b>V2</b>
<test>TestValueGlobal</test>
</global>
<block name="one">
<name>V2</name>
<test>TestValueOfBlock1</test>
</block>
</globalSettings>

doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

I want to get the value of `<test>` from `<globalSettings>` but `<test>` is not always present. Right now, I have 
`doc.Descendants("test").FirstOrDefault()` but it can give me the value of `<test>` from the `<block name="one">`

How do I fix this?

thanks!
RS

Comment: Are you missing some of your XML? It's not well-formed and there is no `<globalSettings>` element.

Comment: Updated! Added the correct ending.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
doc.XPathEvaluate("string(/globalSettings/test)");
```

it should return you the value of `<test>` or an empty string if `<test>` is not there.

Comment: Just found using Elements instead of Descendants will give me immediate child nodes.